# Trigger a mac application to start from a sound or other physical (real world) event

Tags: macos, audio, arduino, javascript

Can anyone offer any advice on options in getting real world events, ie sound, visual, motion, to trigger events on the mac?

The simplest event I think might be sound.

I simply need sound of a certain volume, to start an application on the desktop,

This application would be web based (ie javascript) or possibly standalone.

Most likely the former.

The first thing that comes to mind is Arduino but I was wondering, since I'm a total novice at Arduino coding, if there are other 3rd party apps that might make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of pre-built applications available from the arduino site here:

- http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage

They will all invariably need some customization, but hey that's half the fun right?  Here's an example that seems to do something similar to what you're describing.  You would just need write an app on the computer to listen for the right serial output.

- http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalReadSerial

OR

- http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial

And remember, you can always ask more questions here on SO if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can :)

1) First of all, you'll need the Arduino to "listen" to a sensor. This can be achieved by the digitalRead or analogRead methods, depending which kind of sensor you're gonna use.

2) You'll need send something to your mac when the condition you want to check happens. This involves using the Serial Port to send some kind of message from the Arduino to your mac.

3) On you're mac, you'll need to check messages on the serial port. I often use Processing to listen the serial port. You're lucky, you're on a mac, you have AppleScript :) This means Processing will have to launch a simple Applescript that will tell your selected application to open

That's it. For further details, check google to see how to send messages from arduino to processing, and how to trigger Applescript via Processing